# Create Domain Constraint for SQL

Tags: sql

How would I set domain constraints for the "status" row?
I tried

```
CREATE DOMAIN available_sold TEXT
   CHECK (value = 'available' OR 'sold');
```

but it gave me the following error:

> invalid input syntax for type boolean: "sold"

Comment: Hint:  `IN` is the correct operator.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `value` after OR or  use `IN`

```
CHECK (value = 'available' OR value = 'sold');
```

or

```
CHECK (value IN ('available', 'sold') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking for the [`enum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) type instead of a domain constraint.
Try instead just using this type for the row, sort of like so:

```
available_sold ENUM('available', 'sold')
```

Though, I would probably instead use a column of `sold` with a boolean value, and/or an `available` column, as these values are probably distince and not one or the other.